# How to add Chat bot question and its answer to the pandas data frame so that it can be retrieved at later time when the same question is asked

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, chatbot

**Basic Python Chatbot**

1. An Objective of the task is to create a Basic Python chatbot where any questions asked if the chatbot does not know the answer, it shows request the user to provide the answers. Once the answer is received, it should write that question and its answer it into the pandas dataframe. In the future, a similar question is asked, the chatbot should look into the pandas data frame and give the answer.

   2. Purpose of creating the pandas data frame is that currently, I don't have any ready question and answer, so as time progress I will be adding the question and answer to pandas data frame one by one.

**Blockquote**

```
username = "User"
chatbotname = "<>"
chatbotnameknown = False
active = True

def saychatbot(text):
    global username
    global chatbotname
    global chatbotnameknown
    global active
    if chatbotnameknown:
        print(chatbotname + ": " + text)
    else:
        print("*: " + text)

def speak(user_entry):
    global username
    global chatbotname
    global chatbotnameknown
    global active
    if user_entry == "Hello!" or user_entry == "hello":
        saychatbot("Hi, " + username)
    elif user_entry == "How are you?":
        saychatbot("I'm fine. And you?")
        reply = input("Your answer: ")
        if reply == "Great":
            saychatbot("I'm glad to hear that.")

        else:
                saychatbot("I didn't understand you.")
    elif user_entry == "Bye":
        active = False
    else:
        saychatbot("I didn't understand you.")
        saychatbot("I am still learning, let me learn your language")
        if input("Would you like to teach me your language, Say y/n ? ") == "y":
            saychatbot("You know i am still infancy, so please teach me your language one question and its answer at a time so i will load it in my database!!")

            print("Here I would like to record the question and its answer in Pandas data frame and use that data frame as input to answer the same question in future") 
            print("Is there any way to achieve it") 


def OpenDiscussion():
    global username
    global chatbotname
    global chatbotnameknown
    global active
    print("********Python - Do you know system can speak****************")
    while active:
        if chatbotnameknown:
            speak(str(input(username + ": " + chatbotname + ", ")))
        else:
            speak(str(input(username + ": ")))
    saychatbot("Bye.")
OpenDiscussion()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set up a data structure to store the `<question, answer>` data. In this case, a dictionary would be fine.

If you need use dataframe and add data, `pandas.DataFrame.append` method would help.

Comment: How to bring the questions and answers into dictionary or pandas dataframe from the user inputs dynamically